# Close SWT shell by clicking outside of it

Tags: java, dialog, swt, jface

I have this JFace dialog:

```java
setShellStyle(SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.CLOSE);
setBlockOnOpen(false);
```

Is there a way to make it close by clicking somewhere outside the dialog?
Maybe something like listening for a click event on the whole screen and detecting if it's outside the dialog, and then closing.

Comment: if you have an underlying gui which will always be the same, you can add a listener to that one

Answer (score 4):

You can attach an `SWT.Deactivate` listener to the underlying `Shell` of the dialog.

To attach the listener, you could override `Window::configureShell` like this:

```java
@Override
protected void configureShell(Shell shell) {
  super.configureShell(shell);
  shell.addListener(SWT.Deactivate, event -> shell.close());
}
```

And here a standalone SWT example to illustrate the bare mechanism:

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell parentShell = new Shell(display);
parentShell.setSize(500, 500);
parentShell.open();
Shell shell = new Shell(parentShell);
shell.addListener(SWT.Deactivate, event -> shell.close());
shell.setSize(300, 300);
shell.setText("Closes on Deactivate");
shell.open();
while (!parentShell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch())
    display.sleep();
}
display.dispose();
```

Comment: It seems that the Deactivate event is not triggered when clicking outside the dialog

Comment: I can't reproduce what you describe. Where exactly do you click _outside_ the dialog? I've added a plain SWT example. If you click on the `parentShell` the child shell will be closed and if you click on a shell of a different application, the shell will be closed as well.

Comment: On touch-screens the shell gets also deactivated when a child (enabled) composite gets clicked, so this method wouldn't really work. !

Answer (score 0):

With the `Dialog` being modal I believe that causes some challenges using the `Shell` of the base application to listen for `MouseEvent`s because the `Dialog` intercepts them.

If you're not opposed to using an additional library you could consider using [JNativeHook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) to listen for global mouse click events. This would allow you to listen for a click *anywhere* on the computer and close the dialog if the click occurred outside the dialog bounds, if that's what you're looking for.

For example:

```
GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(new NativeMouseInputAdapter() {
    public void nativeMouseClicked(final NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {
        display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (dialog.getShell() == null || dialog.getShell().isDisposed()) {
                    return;
                }
                // Close the dialog if there is a mouse click outside the bounds of the dialog
                if (!dialog.getShell().getBounds().contains(awtToSwtPoint(nativeMouseEvent.getPoint()))) {
                    dialog.close();
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Other than that, I'm not aware of a way to listen to mouse clicks that are outside of the base application / anywhere on the screen.

---

Full example:

```
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseInputAdapter;

public class DialogCloseTest {

    private final Display display;
    private final Shell shell;

    public DialogCloseTest() {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setSize(450, 450);

        final Dialog dialog = new MyDialog(shell);
        dialog.open();

        registerNativeHook();

        GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(new NativeMouseInputAdapter() {
            public void nativeMouseClicked(final NativeMouseEvent nativeMouseEvent) {
                display.syncExec(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        if (dialog.getShell() == null || dialog.getShell().isDisposed()) {
                            return;
                        }
                        // Close the dialog if there is a mouse click outside the bounds of the dialog
                        if (!dialog.getShell().getBounds().contains(awtToSwtPoint(nativeMouseEvent.getPoint()))) {
                            dialog.close();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point awtToSwtPoint(final java.awt.Point point) {
        return new org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point(point.x, point.y);
    }

    private static void registerNativeHook() {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    private static void unregisterNativeHook() {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException e) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem unregistering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private static class MyDialog extends Dialog {

        MyDialog(final Shell parent) {
            super(parent);
        }

        @Override
        protected void configureShell(final Shell shell) {
            super.configureShell(shell);
            setShellStyle(SWT.APPLICATION_MODAL | SWT.CLOSE);
            setBlockOnOpen(false);
        }    

    }

    public void run() {
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
        unregisterNativeHook();
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new DialogCloseTest().run();
    }

}
```

*Note: This will close the `Dialog` even if it is not visible (eg. if you alt-tab away), so you could add some logic to check whether the dialog is visible as well, if you would like)*